# Unity indoor positioning system resources

Tags: unity-game-engine, indoor-positioning-system

I am looking to set up an AR app implemented on Unity, running in an interior space, with rather precise positioning. Ideally, this will be functional on most smartphones and tablets (hardware-wise) and hopefully (but not necessarily) as a web app.

I am drawing blanks, though, on finding the relevant packages, libraries, implementations or for that matter search terms; all I get on my searches is noise.

To the questions, then:
What's the right technologies to do this? Where should I look for the assets to make it work? And mostly, how should I search for resources on the subject?

Comment: Do you need precise location and do you have a budget? Quuppa is exactly that but it requires an installation and is not free. Other way could be to place markers in the rooms to adjust the player position. So when the AR detects a specific image, it knows where that position is and can place the player back. This along with SLAM technology already detecting acceleration.

Comment: Ideally, I would know when the device is quite close to some set points, and without needing the user to wave the camera around. Budget is a tricky subject, best kept to a minimum and best a matter of physical installation as opposed to development (so the software can be developed for free and any cost is contingent on actually putting it to use). In any case, it's critical it can work in Unity and that most user devices can walk into the room with little to no preparation and function.